# PHP Include for static remote HTML files on a CDN

Tags: php, cdn

I have an app that creates static HTML files. The files are intended to be hosted on a remote CDN, they'd be standard .html files.

I am wondering two things:

1. If it's possible to do a PHP include on these files?
2. Can you possibly have good performance doing it this way?

Comment: You can either redirect (statically) to the CDN files to benefit from the CDN or cache them on your local server if you need to adjust them - please let us know the specific use case here

Comment: I want to use include because I want to control the URL the user is seeing. So I will grab the file and serve it on a specific URL.

Comment: When you want to use include consider caching the file on your local server - otherwise your server needs to download the file on every request.

Comment: Unless you are going to optimise the set up of your web server and the way it handles responses, I would strongly advise not serving the file from your server as you will lose the benefits and optimisations of the CDN. CDN's are not just used to house and serve content from the nearest edge location, they also strip out all the unecessary headers, cookies etc, and not to mention, they will handle the compression and caching of the assets that are served to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Can it be done?

To answer the question directly, yes, you technically can include a remote file using the PHP `include` function. In order to do this, you simply need to set the [`allow_url_include`](https://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) directive to `On` in your php.ini.

Depending on exactly what you intend to use this for, I would also encourage you to look at [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

To enable remote files for `file_get_contents`, you will need to set [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to `On`.

## Should it be done?

To answer your second question directly, there are many factors that will determine whether you will get good performance, but all in all, it is unlikely to make a dramatic difference to performance.

However, there are other considerations:

- From a security perspective, it is ill-advised to enable either of these directives
- By delivering the file from your server instead of the CDN you will be negating all of the benefits of the CDN (see below)
- Is it ***really*** necessary?

## CDNs

A frequent misunderstanding when it comes to CDNs is that all they do is serve your data from a closer location, thus it makes the request slightly faster... This is wrong!

There are endless benefits to CDN's, but I have listed a few below (obviously depends on configuration and provider):

- They strip out unnecessary headers
- No cookies are sent as the CDN tends to be on a different, thus cookie-free, domain
- They handle compression
- They deliver your content from the nearest location
- They handle caching
- ... and a lot more

By serving the file from your server, you will lose all of the above benefits, unless, of course, you set the server up to handle requests in the same way (this can take time).

To conclude; personally, I would avoid including your `.html` files into PHP remotely and just serve them directly to the client from the CDN.

To see how you can further optimise your site, and to see the many benefits that most CDNs offer, take a look at [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).